# Implement Google translation

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, google-translate

I use Google Translate to translate names from language to another using c#.

I'm trying to do the same using MS Access VBA.

Working c# code.

```
public string trans_arabic_to_english(string word)
        {
            var toLanguage = "en";//English
            var fromLanguage = "ar";//Deutsch
            var url = $"https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl={fromLanguage}&tl={toLanguage}&dt=t&q={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(word)}";
            var webClient = new WebClient
            {
                Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
            };
            var result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
            try
            {
                result = result.Substring(4, result.IndexOf("\"", 4, StringComparison.Ordinal) - 4);
                return result;
            }
            catch
            {
                return "Error";
            }
        }
```

Attempt in VBA code.

```vb
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim toLan As String, fromLan As String, resp As String, s As String, a_name As String, url As String

toLang = "ar"
fromlang = "en"
a_name = "omar khalil"
url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?"
url = url & "client=gtx&sl={""" & toLang & """}&tl={""" & fromlang & """}&dt=t&q={""" & a_name & """}"

url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl="
url = url & fromlang & "&tl=" & to_lang & "&dt=t&q=" & a_name
'==
Dim ob As Object
Set ob = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
ob.Open "POST", url, False
ob.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
ob.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
ob.Send
If ob.Status <> 200 Then
resp = ob.ResponseText
MsgBox resp
End Sub
```

I also tried WinHttp.

Comment: Can you share what you tried (in VBA)?

Comment: done,you can check it

Comment: Please, check my answer function code. it uses "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next function, please:

```
Private Function GTranslate(strInput As String, strFromLang As String, strToLang As String) As String
    Dim strURL As String, objHTTP As Object, objHTML As Object, objDivs As Object, objDiv As Variant
    
    strURL = "https://translate.google.com/m?hl=" & strFromLang & _
        "&sl=" & strFromLang & _
        "&tl=" & strToLang & _
        "&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=" & strInput
        
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.Send ""
    
    Set objHTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    With objHTML
        .Open
        .Write objHTTP.responseText
        .Close
    End With
    
    Set objDivs = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each objDiv In objDivs
        'If objDiv.className = "t0" Then              'it does not work, anymore
        If objDiv.className = "result-container" Then 'adapted on December 28th
            GTranslate = objDiv.innerText: Exit For
        End If
    Next objDiv
    
    Set objHTML = Nothing: Set objHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

It can be called in the next way:

```
Sub testTranslateG()
  MsgBox GTranslate("Este es un libro", "auto", "en")
End Sub
```

The second parameter can be "auto" (like in the testing Sub), or the specific language abbreviation if more accurate translation needed ("es" - Spanish, "ru" - Russian, "ro" - Romanian etc.).

In order to find the correct abbreviation, you can open Google Translate page, right click and choose 'View page source'. Then try finding some language. Let us say Spanish. In that area you will see a script having strings like the following one: "code:'it',name:'Italian'". Easy to understand that "it" is the abbreviation for Italian...

Comment: it was working fine for 3 months and now its not working i have tried so many codes but now it returns invalid translation , can you try it please or advice me what should i do ? thanks in advanced

Comment: @omarzKH: If it worked and suddenly doesn't, they maybe changed the involved class name... Let me check and if I find something I will try suggesting the solution.

Comment: Adapted the code with the new working class. Changed the line `If objDiv.className = "t0" Then` with `If objDiv.className = "result-container" Then`. Please, test it. I made only a few tests and it looked working...

Comment: i have already tried this but with no luck